# Dropbox.com works in VM host but not guest, all other sites work in guest

Tags: linux, networking, macos, ssl, vmware

Dropbox.com works in VM host but not guest, all other sites work in guest.

Host: MacOS 11

VM: VMWare Fusion 12

Guest: Arch Linux, VM NAT networking

No iptables rules in VM.
ca-certificates (20210603-1) and ca-certificates-mozilla (3.76-1) updated today in guest.

Normal browsing to various sites works in both host and guest.
dropbox.com works in host but not in guest

In guest:

```
$ curl -vvvvv https://dropbox.com ; echo $?
*   Trying 162.125.248.18:443...
* Connected to dropbox.com (162.125.248.18) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to dropbox.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to dropbox.com:443 
35
```

In host:

```
$ curl -v https://dropbox.com
*   Trying 2620:100:6040:18::a27d:f812...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to dropbox.com (2620:100:6040:18::a27d:f812) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):

...omitting further details of successful curl...
```

Wireshark in guest shows that I send a TLSv1 Client Hello and then dropbox.com replies with TCP ACK and then a TCP RST,ACK. This also happens if I capture firefox and chromium trying to open dropbox.com in the guest.

From the above `curl`s I notice that in the host machine IPv6 is used but IPv4 is used in guest VM.

In an Arch Linux native box I get the same curl output as in the guest above until the reset, except that the IPv6 address is used (as in the host example above) and that there is a single additional line between the `CApath: none` and the Client Hello line, namely, `} [5 bytes data]`. The rest of the curl output in the native box is successful.